# ffmpeg Output file #0 does not contain any stream during the extraction of audio from a .webm file

Tags: ffmpeg

my objective is to extract frames and corresponding audio from a .webm file. Then crop the faces shown in those frames and resize the cropped images to 256x256 and concatenate them back to a video with that specific audio.

To make it more clear,

1. Extract the required frames from the video and their corresponding audio.
2. Crop the faces of those frames and resize them to 256x256.
3. Concatenate the faces back to a video with the corresponding audio.

The problems come at stage 1 and 3.

For instance, I am extracting the frames using the following command:

`ffmpeg -loglevel error -i /download_youtube/_5rNOD1nsDg.webm -vf "select=between(n\,576\,768),setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -qscale:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -vsync 0 extracted_hq_results/_5rNOD1nsDg/Clip+_5rNOD1nsDg+P0+C0+F575-769/%08d.jpg` 
It will give me the images of the video from the frames.

When I try to extract the audio from the .webm.   `ffmpeg -i _5rNOD1nsDg.webm -vn -y -ar 44100 -ac 2 output.wav`

I get something like below and there is not any .wav file generated.
 `Input #0, matroska,webm, from '_5rNOD1nsDg.webm': Metadata: encoder         : google/video-file Duration: 00:10:08.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18219 kb/s Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default) Output #0, wav, to 'output.wav': Output file #0 does not contain any stream`

My question is how can I use ffmpeg to extract audio given a range of time or frames I want from a .webm file.